# ddclient not working with namecheap on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ddclient

This is my /etc/ddclient.conf:

```
daemon=300
ssl=yes
use=web
web=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/getip
protocol=namecheap
server=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com
# First Domain
login=firstdomain.com
password='password'
@.firstdomain.com, *.firstdomain.com
# Second Domain
login=seconddomain.com
password='password'
@.seconddomain.com, *.seconddomain.com
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Try following their instructions:  https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/583/11/how-do-i-configure-ddclient/  But, you have given us no other information like OS and version that you are using, any error messages that you are getting.  Just telling us that it doesn't work makes it so that all we can do is guess.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1434439/edit) your question and give a lot more details so that we can help you better.  Thank you!

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 The docs are for a single domain only They don't say how to setup for multiple domains Why would I run a system service for one domain

Comment: Did you read down into the discussion below those instructions?  https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/583/11/how-do-i-configure-ddclient/  Really from what it is looking like is that it is up to namecheap for support of multiple domains in the ddclient.conf file.  "Why would I run a system service for one domain?"  I do for mine.  I have no need for multiple domains and it works great for me since my ISP gives me a dynamic public IP.  I don't use namecheap though.